# Traverse a tree represented by its edges

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, time-complexity, depth-first-search

My tree is represented by its edges and the root node. The edge list is **undirected**.

```
char[][] edges =new char[][]{
    new char[]{'D','B'},
    new char[]{'A','C'},
    new char[]{'B','A'}             
};

char root='A';
```

The tree is

```
  A
 B  C
D
```

How do I do depth first traversal on this tree? What is the time complexity?

I know  time complexity of depth first traversal on linked nodes is O(n). But if the tree is represented by edges, I feel the time complexity is O(n^2). Am I wrong?

Giving code is appreciated, although I know it looks like homework assignment..

Comment: What is your reasoning for O(n^2)?  (Note that there are ways to represent the edges so that DFT is O(n); this may or may not be one of them.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general template behind DFS looks something like this:

```
 function DFS(node) {
     if (!node.visited) {
         node.visited = true;
         for (each edge {node, v}) {
             DFS(v);
         }
     }
 }
```

If you have your edges represented as a list of all the edges in the graph, then you could implement the for loop by iterating across all the edges in the graph and, every time you find one with the current node as its source, following the edge to its endpoint and running a DFS from there. If you do this, then you'll do O(m) work per node in the graph (here, m is the number of edges), so the runtime will be O(mn), since you'll do this at most once per node in the graph. In a tree, the number of edges is always O(n), so for a tree the runtime is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

That said, if you have a tree and there are only n edges, you can speed this up in a bunch of ways. First, you could consider doing an O(n log n) preprocessing step to sort the array of edges. Then, you can find all the edges leaving a given node by doing a binary search to find the first edge leaving the node, then iterating across the edges starting there to find just the edges leaving the node. This improves the runtime quite a bit: you do O(log n) work per node for the binary search, and then every edge gets visited only once. This means that the runtime is O(n log n). Since you've mentioned that the edges are undirected, you'll actually need to create two different copies of the edges array - one that's the original one, and one with the edges reversed - and should sort each one independently. The fact that DFS marks visited nodes along the way means that you don't need to do any extra bookkeeping here to figure out which direction you should go at each step, and this doesn't change the overall time complexity, though it does increase the space usage.

Alternatively, you could use a hashing-based solution. Before doing the DFS, iterate across the edges and convert them into a hash table whose keys are the nodes and whose values are lists of the edges leaving that node. This will take expected time O(n). You can then implement the "for each edge" step quite efficiently by just doing a hash table lookup to find the edges in question. This reduces the time to (expected) O(n), though the space usage goes up to O(n) as well. Since your edges are undirected, as you populate the table, just be sure to insert the edge in each direction.

Comment: Yeah, the root node is given. Solely from an edge list, any node can be root node.

Comment: I forgot to mention The edge list is undirected.

Comment: @LoveRight That's a pretty big change. :-)